# MaterializeCSS collapsible not working with v-for loop in vue js

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, materialize

I just started implementing Vue JS to my existing project with having very basic knowledge and minimal implementation.

My entire project is on Codeigniter 3 as backend framework and using html5, css3 and jQuery as frontend technology. I don't want to use other substitute frontend framework other than materializesCss, vue.js and of-course jQuery (at least for some time, till I am fully familiar with vue.js).

well, coming to the point, in my FAQ, which is dynamically generated from the data I got from the database; I am using materialise collapsible. The general code structure is:

```
<span v-for="category in categories">
    <h6><i :class="category.cat_icon"></i> {{ category.title }}</h6>
    <ul class="collapsible">
        <li v-for="faq in faqs">
            <div class="collapsible-header" v-if="faq.fc_id === category.c_id"><i class="icofont-dotted-right"></i> {{ faq.q }}</div>
            <div class="collapsible-body" v-if="faq.fc_id === category.c_id"><span>{{ faq.a }} </span></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</span>
```

...
necessary js file includes
...

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.collapsible').collapsible();
    });
    </script>

    <script>
    var app = new Vue({
        el: "#faq",
        data: {
            title: "Frequently Asked Questions",
            categories: [],
            faqs: [],
            recommends: []
        },
        mounted() {
           axios.get("<?php echo base_url('getFaqCategories');?>")
                .then(response => {
                    this.categories = response.data
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                })
                .then(function(){
                    $('.collapsible').collapsible();
                }),
            axios.get("<?php echo base_url('getFaqs');?>")
                .then(response => {
                    this.faqs = response.data
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                })
                .then(function(){
                    $('.collapsible').collapsible();
                }),
            axios.get("<?php echo base_url('recommended');?>")
                .then(response => {
                this.recommends = response.data
            })
        }
    });
    </script>
```

The sequence of included js files are, [1] jQuery [2] materialize.js [3]vue.min.js [4] axios.min.js

Now the strange part is, it is working perfectly in my localhost but after uploading it to my production server (AWS EC2), nothing happens when clicking to the list.

No error is displaying.
Quick suggestion welcomed, please keep in mind that I am having very basic knowledge about vue.js.

Comment: The initialisation should come after the component is built - is that the case here?

Comment: To add to Sean Doherty's comment, you're initializing the collapse functionality as soon as the document is ready, but you're making async calls for data after the component is mounted, and the collapsible elements cannot be rendered until that data has been returned. At the moment you'd need to use Promise.all for the categories and faq, and then put the initialization of the collapsible into the success method of promise.all.